# How to have the data-id of an element when you click on it?

Tags: javascript, dataset

I create several buttons and I give them an id in a loop and I would like that when we click on it, its id is displayed in the console.
This is what I tried to do but the program returns the last id assigned after the loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.textContent = "Add to cart"; 
button.setAttribute("data-id", i+1);
card.appendChild(button);
button.onclick = function() {
  let attribut = button.getAttribute("data-id");
  console.log(attribut)
};
```

}

Comment: Please edit your question and place `code` in code blocks properly, your `}` is outside code blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `onclick` gets called, `button` is still set to the last button in your loop; there's no reference to `button` in your `onclick`. Instead, try passing the event (`e`) into the `onclick`, then reference the event's target with `e.target`.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.textContent = "Add to cart"; 
  button.setAttribute("data-id", i+1);
  document.body.appendChild(button);
  button.onclick = function(e) {
    let attribut = e.target.getAttribute("data-id");
    console.log(attribut)
  };
}
```